# Why is it showing 'guvectorize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'signature' ' for a package such as resampy

Tags: python, librosa

I was trying to import librosa which gave me multiple errors like the absence of audioread, resampy etc. I tried to install all these manually. It is still showing an error in resampy.

```
C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\resampy\interpn.py in <module>
     73 @guvectorize(
     74     "(n),(m),(p),(p),(),()->(m)",
---> 75     nopython=True,
     76 )
     77 def resample_f_p(x, t_out, interp_win, interp_delta, num_table, scale, y):

TypeError: guvectorize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'signature'
```

Comment: the error is clear:  missing 1 required positional argument: 'signature'

Answer (score 11):

I solved the error by downgrading 'resampy' from version 0.4.2 to 0.3.1.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade 'resampy' from version 0.4.2 to 0.2.2